# Network not changing

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g2

Whenever I am trying to change my mobile data from SIM 2 to SIM 1 its not working, it says data subscription change in progress but it never change actually.

Settings - Sim cards - preferred sim for mobile data. Moto G2 - 6.0

I tried all the scenarios changed SIM card disable enable all scenarios but no luck.

Can someone please provide me some guidance on the same so that i can switch data to other network.

Thank You.